# Range based on cell value

Tags: vba, excel, variables, range

I need code to change the range based on a cell value:

I can get it to work where the row number is dependent on the cell value as shown below, but I need the column value to be variable:

```
For Nassets = 1 To ws_data.Range("d2")
ws_data.Range("B" & Nassets).Value = 3
Next Nassets
```

If `"d2"` have the value `4`, range `B1:B4 = 3`, however I want range `B4:E4 = 3`

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments below, it look like you need to change the code so that the value in D2 represents the **column** within your loop, not the **row** - In which case:

```
For Nassets = 1 To ws_data.Range("d2")
    ws_data.Cells(4, Nassets).Value = 3 '// Where 4 is the row number
Next Nassets
```

This can be re-written to exlude the loop altogether like so:

```
ws_data.Range(Cells(4, 2), Cells(4, ws_data.Range("D2").Value)).Value = 3
```

Comment: Yes, but the "d2" value can change to any given number, and therefore i would not be certain of the ":E". what i know is that i want it to start at row 4, and move to Column "X" depending on the value at "d2"

Comment: So where does the column number come from? Is it in another cell? this isn't clear in your question.

Comment: It comes from the value in "d2" - for example if "d2" = 6, then the range should be "B4:G4"

Comment: Based on your example - if D2 contains "6" then you would go up B6 as it controls the row number. How can this cell have the row _and_ the column number?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, the row number is fixed. the number in D2 is the column number

Comment: Okay, so you want the number in D2 to change the **column** number, not the **row** number which it is currently doing?